# SQLite [Err] 21 - not an error

Tags: sqlite, schema

I have the following code in SQL

```
-- SCHEMA VERSION: 2

-- Pre-update actions
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
-- end

-- Create HARVEST_PERIOD table
CREATE TABLE "main"."HARVEST_PERIOD" (
"ID"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"CODE"  TEXT(64) NOT NULL,
"PERIOD"  TEXT(64) NOT NULL,
"CURRENT_STATE"  TEXT(128)
)
;

-- Post-update actions
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "main"."SETTINGS" ("NAME", "VALUE") values ("SchemaVersion", "2");
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
-- end
```

The new table is created as expected and the settings table updated as expected, too. What could be the reason for getting this: **[Err] 21 - not an error**
Is there any better suggested way to create the new schema?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error as well. Later I figured it out. It's because another application was connected to the same db. So, my application can't modify the db -- create a table.
I created it successfully  just by closing the another db connection.